# Provision lambda concurrency in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-cdk

I am trying to provision lambda concurrency via CDK. I have a couple of CfnFunctions and I need to provision them.

Provisioning can be done on aliases only. Hence, when I add autoPublishAlias to the CfnFunction, the APIG trigger does not work.

How can the provisioning be achieved (configured) via CDK?

Thanks,
Vinod.

Comment: There's not enough information here. What have you tried? Need more specifics.

Comment: What language are you using with the cdk?

Comment: What are you trying to get? i have a working piece of code with CfnFunctions and API Gateway.

Comment: @AmitBaranes can you please share the code?
I have a working piece of APIG and CfnFunction. But, I am trying to provision the CfnFunction via CDK.

Comment: @jmp The language is Java.

Comment: @JustinSkiles I have a CfnFunction. I have tried creating a auto alias publish. The auto alias creation works fine. However, I need to fetch the alias in CDK and provision it, and link the APIG trigger to the alias. I am not sure how this can be done via CDK.

Comment: @Rishi everything can be done :)

Comment: @Rishi did my answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923751/112233

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example in Typescript:

On this site there is an example in typescript:
https://github.com/iph/lambda-experiments/blob/master/pc-asg/lib/pc-asg-stack.ts#L33

1. First create your lambda function;
2. Create your alias (the version
   must be recovered from your lambda, through the currentVersion
   property);
3. Create a ScalableTarget, in this step you will use
   information created in the previous steps (functionName and
   aliasName);
4. It's very important that you include this line in the
   target.node.addDependency(alias) code, without that you will get an
   error, for some reason the cdk when trying to create the
   ScalableTarget doesn't wait until the alias is created, this line
   makes it wait for the alias to be created for then, create the
   ScalableTarget;
5. Finally configure scaleToTrackMetric with the data
   to make the provisioned concurrency scale automatically;

Comment: Thanks man. I had allot of issues to get this to work. target.node.addDependency(alias) was the issue solver.

Comment: The OP is asking for provisioned concurrency. Your answer is about autoscaling. These are two different things.

Answer (score 4):

I think I got it:

**Java code**

```
package YOURPACKAGENAMEHERE;

import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Construct;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Stack;
import java.util.UUID;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Duration;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Alias;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.AliasProps;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Code;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Function;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.IFunction;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Runtime;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.SingletonFunction;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Version;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.VersionProps;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.iam.Role;

public class JavacdexampleStack extends Stack {

    public JavacdexampleStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        super(scope, id);

        //create Lambda function
        SingletonFunction lambdaFunction =
        SingletonFunction.Builder.create(this, "cdk-lambda-example")
            .description("Lambda which prints \"I'm running\"")
            .code(Code.fromInline("def main(event, context):\n" + "    print(\"I'm running!\")\n"))
            .handler("index.main")
            .timeout(Duration.seconds(300))
            .runtime(Runtime.PYTHON_3_7)
            .uuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .role(Role.fromRoleArn(this, "roleId", "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/116CD745-C8DA-4569-8058-828EFA93E6D7"))//replace with your execution role or create one in cdk
            .build();

        IFunction lambda = Function.fromFunctionArn(this, "functionId", lambdaFunction.getFunctionArn());

        //create version for alias to be assigned to
        VersionProps versionprop = new VersionProps.Builder()
            .lambda(lambda)
        //assign version which the alias points to with provisioned concurrency
            .provisionedConcurrentExecutions(5)
            .build();

        Version version = new Version(this, "versionId", versionprop);

        //create alias
        AliasProps aliasprops = new AliasProps.Builder()
            .aliasName("YourAliasNameHere")
            .version(version)
            .build();
        Alias alias = new Alias(this,"aliasId", aliasprops);

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image: provisionedConcurrencyImage]

**preliminary steps taken**

```sh
# assumes npm and mvn are installed
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
npm install -g aws-cdk
cdk --version
    # pasting here for visability on which version I used
    1.22.0 (build 309ac1b)

mkdir javacdkexample
cd javacdkexample 
cdk init --language java

# recommended to run after creating the project from docs
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html#getting_started_update
mvn versions:use-latest-versions
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- AWS Cloud Development Kit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>events-targets</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I assume you were looking for provisioned concurrency?

Comment: Yes, looking for provisioned concurrency, but, for a serverless lambda which is triggered vida APIG.

Answer (score 1):

this is from the official doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html#autoscaling